# angular 2 material table date column mix string

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

In my date column when dates are not set or blank I want to display the string "Not Set". I also want it to sort correctly so Not Set dates are highest in value and shown last when sorted ascending. How do you guys handle this scenario in your apps. Right now I am showing some high value like 09/09/9999 just so it sorts correctly but user is confused since it should really say "Not Set". 
I cannot assign strings to a date column and cannot put dates in a string column for the sorting to work right so in a tailspin right now.
Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mix types like below.

`let date: String|Date`

That way, you allow `date` to be either String or Date type.

Comment: Unknown token. Parser error. What should I google for to get info on mixing types like you indicated. Any sample link ?Thanks

Comment: @Gullu That is the correct syntax for mixing types, so I think the "Unknown token. Parser error" comes from something else. Check for misplaced or missing semicolons?

Comment: See this stackblitz where iam trying to make Name column take String or Date. If you remove your syntax, errors go away. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kjt8gt

Comment: I see where the confusion came from. You need to define types in your ts file not in your html template.

Comment: e.g. `export interface PeriodicElement {
  name: string;
  position: number;
  weight: number;
  symbol: string | Date;
}
`

Comment: @Gullu Here's an updated stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kjt8gt-ubphhz